# SQL query for joining tables

Tags: sql

I have four tables and want to create a new table with only row per client.

**CLIENT**

```
id  |   fname  |   lname   |   city  |  company_id

1   |   kim    |   smith   |   jhb   |  1
2   |   tom    |   jones   |   ct    |  1
3   |   john   |   short   |   pe    |  2
```

**CLIENT_DIVISION**

```
id   |  client_id  |  division_id

1    |  1          |  1
2    |  1          |  2
3    |  2          |  1
4    |  2          |  3
5    |  2          |  4
6    |  3          |  4
7    |  3          |  2
```

**DIVISION**

```
id  |  name

1   |  estate
2   |  property
3   |  litigation
4   |  commercial
```

**COMPANY**

```
id  | name

1   | compA
2   | compB
```

**DESIRED TABLE RESULT** when query for divisions = estate

```
id  |  fname  | lname  | city  |  company_name

1   |  kim    | smith  | jhb   |  compA
2   |  tom    | jones  | ct    |  compA
```

I would like to be able to create a new table with one row per client where division parameters are passed to the query. The parameters passed will come from check boxes that the user selects before submitting the query. How do I create a join-query for that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query will help you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT     CLIENT.id, CLIENT.fname, CLIENT.lname, CLIENT.city, COMPANY.name
FROM         CLIENT INNER JOIN
                  CLIENT_DIVISION ON CLIENT.id = CLIENT_DIVISION.client_id INNER JOIN
                  COMPANY ON CLIENT.company_id = COMPANY.id INNER JOIN
                  DIVISION ON CLIENT_DIVISION.division_id = DIVISION.id
WHERE     (DIVISION.id = @division_id)
```

You need  to replace @division_id with you value.

Comment: Sorry. I used the above script and run the queries and it returned the same clients even when I changed the @division_id.

Comment: If client belongs to more than one division, I require the client record to only appear once.

Comment: To display only unique records you need to add DISTINCT after SELECT.

Comment: I tested my query on your data and it returns different records when i replace @division_id by 1, 2, 3 or 4.